# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, tcpclient, sslstream, nominet

I am maintaining our Nominet domains through their EPP System.

To do this is I am instantiating a TCP client and connecting using an ssl stream, everything is working fine locally in my virtual machine using both IIS and IIS Express.

However, when I deploy to our test server I get the error message "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream".

I have tried disabling the firewall, and running fiddler but neither have helped, anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for anyone else who is struggling with this.

The issue is that with Nominets EPP system you have to specify the public IP address of the server you are running the EPP code from for security purposes.

As we are behind a firewall my development machine public IP and server public IP are the same therefore I didn't think I needed to change anything.

However, I noticed that when I was finding out my public IP for my dev machine it was shown as IPV4 and the test server was shown in IPV6 format although both had the same IPV4 address wasn't sure how I could get the test server to report its IPV4 address therefore simply added both IPS to Nominet and it now works fine.

Thanks

Ant

Comment: urmm ... so ... I just had this problem too ... whilst working with Nominet and integrating against a test server they provided!!! I'll tell them to update their IP list. Thanks!